# Rails - Conditional statement in form recognizing wrong url paramater

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, request, hidden-field

I have a polymorphic relationship between Attachments and Users & Teams so that both users and teams can upload attachments. The :team_id or :user_id is passed along as a param when the "Add file" button is clicked. Then, a hidden field in the attachments#new form tells the controller if the request is coming from a Team or User so that attribute_update can be applied to the proper model. In practice, however, the team request is being delivered as user subaction and vice versa. Any ideas as to what may be going wrong?

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :upload, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :upload
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :upload
end
```

team#show

```
<%= link_to "Add Files", new_attachment_path(:team_id => @team.id), class: "btn btn-md" %>
```

user#show

```
<%= link_to "Add Files", new_attachment_path(:user_id => current_user), class: "btn btn-md" %>
```

attachments#new

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add file') %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@attachment) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.file_field :file %>

      <% if request.path == new_attachment_path(params[:team_id]) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:subaction, 'Team') %>
      <% elsif request.path == new_attachment_path(params[:user_id]) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:subaction, 'User') %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit "Add Files", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

attachment controller

```
def create
    @attachment = Attachment.create(attachment_params)
    @team = Team.find_by(params[:team_id])
    @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
    if @attachment.save
      if params[:subaction] == 'Team'
        @attachment.update_attribute(:upload, @team)
        flash[:success] = "Team file uploaded!"
        redirect_to @team
      elsif params[:subaction] == 'User'
        @attachment.update_attribute(:upload, @user)
        flash[:success] = "User file uploaded!"
        redirect_to current_user
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: I replaced 'polynomial' relationship with 'polymorphic'. Your params don't look like you defined a polymorphic relationship in the Rails sense, though. I don't see why the 'vice versa' behaviour emerges, though. How did you analyze this behaviour?

Comment: Thank you. When I add an attachment from the team page, the subaction is registered as 'User'. When I add an attachment from the user page, the subaction is registered as 'Team'

Comment: Define "is registered as"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the url param to pass the string 'User' or 'Team' instead of the team_id or user_id allowing the controller if statement to function properly.

Team#show

```
<%= link_to "Add Files", new_attachment_path(:upload_type => 'Team'), class: "btn btn-md" %>
```

User#show

```
<%= link_to "Add Files", new_attachment_path(:upload_type => 'User'), class: "btn btn-md" %>
```

Attachments#new

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add file') %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@attachment) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.file_field :file %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag(:subaction, params[:upload_type]) %>

      <%= f.submit "Add Files", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, passing the params[:upload_type] is better than my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your `if` statement in `attachments#new`. Both params[:team_id] and params[:user_id] would return an integer so your `if` statement can't really tell if the request is coming from a team or a user. As a suggestion you could store your `params[:team_id]` in a variable such as `@team_id` and then change your if statement to something like this:

```
<% unless @team_id.nil? %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:subaction, 'Team') %>
<% else%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:subaction, 'User') %>
<% end %>
```

However you may be able to improve this further by using polymorphic associations in your models as outlined in the following link: https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails

Comment: The association is set up as polymoprhic, I've edited the post to include the models for attachments, users, and teams. The only reason I put the url params in the first place was so I could differentiate where the request came from.

Comment: The problem is still with the `if` statement I have outlined.

Comment: agreed, thank you for pointing out that the if statement only recognizes that an integer has been passed. I changed the url param so that 'Team' or 'User' would be passed instead of the id. Answer below.